# SQL add up all values in column per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a graph and need to generate an array from the information in a sales table which I have. It's columns include DATE (2010-09-30 13:48:58) and AMOUNT (4.99). What's in brackets are examples of the type of data in each column.

What I would like to do in SQL is to go through the table and get totals of the amount for each month so that I can create an array with it.

How do I do this in SQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple aggregate.

This is quite standard SQL too (subject to delimiting names that are reserved keywords)

```
SELECT
    YEAR(`Date`) As TheYear, MONTH(`Date`) AS TheMonth, 
    SUM(Amount) AS MonthlyTotal
FROM 
    SomeTable
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(`Date`), MONTH(`Date`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(`Date`) As `Year`, MONTH(`Date`) AS `Month`, SUM(`Amount`) AS `MonthlyTotal`
FROM `myTable`
GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), MONTH(`Date`)
```

It's worth pointing out that you should really avoid using column names like `Date` and `Amount`

Comment: I assume you haven't tested this on MySQL? Your answer is T-SQL so did you test on SQL Server? Either way, it will fail...